# add link_to to image tag with instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the code below and I want to add the link to, as it is with the Gravatar, to the first line. It should link to user.

```
<section class="user_info">
      <% if @user.avatar.file? %>
        <div class="s3_avatar"> <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:square) %></div>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to((gravatar_for @user, size: 100), @user ) %>
      <% end %>
      <h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:square) %>`
try the following:

```
<%= link_to user_path(@user) do %>
  <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:square) %>
<% end %>
```

Refer to [UrlHelper::link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for more info.